# SQL Server Statistics Update

Tags: sql-server

I manage 25 SQL Server databases.  All 25 databases are configured to "Auto Update Statistics".  A few of these databases are 250+ GB and contain tables with 2+ billion records. The "Auto Update Statistics" setting is not sufficient to effectively keep the larger database statistics updated.  I created a nightly job to update stats for all databases and tables with fullscan.  This fixed our performance issues initially, but now the job is taking too long (7 hours).

How can I determine which tables need a full scan statistics update?  Can I use a value from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats or some other DMV?

Using SQL Sever 2019 (version 15.0.2080.9) and the compatibility level of the databases is SQL Server 2016 (130).

Comment: A lot of SQL Server admins use Ola Hallengren's SQL Server Backup, Integrity Check, and Index and Statistics Maintenance sctipts https://ola.hallengren.com/  Read through the information on SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance and keep in mind fullscan of all indexes should be done rarely - weekly or less.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? If less than 2016 you'll probably want to use [Trace Flag 2371](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/c361fd8d-51b8-f60a-c242-1383979957bd) or, like Brian suggested, take a more proactive approach than relying on the default/automatic behavior. Though you probably want somewhere between "don't do anything" and "fullscan every single table every night."

Comment: The host server is using SQL Sever 2019 (version 15.0.2080.9).  The compatibility level of the databases is SQL Server 2016 (130).  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

As of **Sql2016+** (db compatibility level 130+), the [main formula used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-2017#auto_update_statistics-option) to decide if stats need updating is: `MIN ( 500 + (0.20 * n), SQRT(1,000 * n) )`. In the formula, `n` is the count of rows in the table/index in question. You then compare the result of the formula to how many rows have been modified since the statistic was last updated. That's found at either `sys.sysindexes.rowmodctr` or `sys.dm_db_stats_properties(...).row_count` (they have the same value).

[Ola's scripts also use this formula](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html#StatisticsModificationLevel), internally, but you can use the `StatisticsModificationLevel` param, to be more aggressive, if you want (e.g. [like Erin Stellato](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/updating-statistics-with-ola-hallengrens-script/)). The main reason people (like Erin) give to be more aggressive is if you know your tables have a lot of skew or churn.

If you find your problem is that a *filtered* index isn't getting updated automatically, be aware of a [long-standing issue that could be the cause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94430/26074).

However, ultimately, I believe the reason you have a performance problem with your nightly statistics job is because you're blindly updating **all** statistics for **every** table. It's better to update only the statistics that need it---especially since [you can cause an IO storm](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/01/update-statistics-the-secret-io-explosion/).